# Express-session - Concurrent modifications on session

Tags: node.js, express, session, concurrency, session-store

I'm implementing a session-based services using expressjs and express-session with the redis-connect store in nodejs and I have a problem with the concurrent modifications on session storage. Find following an example of the problem:

- Two routes published: /api/op1 and /api/op2
- /api/op1: Increment the value of request.session.op1Calls and performs calls to external services (3 seconds)
- /api/op2: Increment the value of request.session.op2Calls and just do nothing (0.1 ms to be executed)

The problem here is: If I execute the op2 several times during the execution of op1, the request.session.op2Calls value is just lost. How should I implement the session store to never lose the values?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code that specifically increments the `.session.opXCalls` ?

Comment: It is just: request.session.opxCalls++ (if the parameter is not defined, I'm using request.session.opxCalls = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express session ( `request.session` ) is being read from the store ( in your case redis store ) at the moment the request was made.

Having the request doing the task and *then* modify the session and save it back to the store will actually save the already *read* session enriched with the updated properties.

What you can do to mitigate this is to have the session reloaded before save :

```
app.get( "/op2", function( req, res, next ) {
   someReallyLongAsyncTask( function() {
       req.session.reload(function(err) {    
           if ( !req.session.op2Call ) { req.session.op2Call = 0; }
           req.session.op2Call++;
           req.session.save( function() { 
               res.json( { success: true } )
           } );
       } );
   } );    
} );
```

This way you will make sure that the session is re-read before being saved.